# How to reference a method return value in a subsequent method?

Tags: c#, methods, return-value

I am just wondering if there is a way to simplify this code:

```
var myStr = GetThatValue();
myStr = myStr.Substring(1, myStr.Length - 2); // remove first and last chars
```

into this:

```
// how to get hold of GetThatValue return value?
var myStr = GetThatValue().Substring(1, hereWhat.Length - 2);
```

I though about `this` keyword but it does not work in this context. It will reference the class instance as expected.

Comment: @MairajAhmad he needs to know what  `hereWhat` should be..

Comment: Another alternative to storing the value in a variable(which is recommended). You could modify `GetThatValue` to take arguments `int start, int length`. Then let `GetThatValue` do the `Substring`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.  The alternative is this:

```
var myStr = GetThatValue().Substring(1, GetThatValue().Length - 2);
```

Which, as you can see, invokes `GetThatValue()` twice.  So if that operation is expensive or returns different values then it probably shouldn't be re-invoked.

Even if it's not an expensive operation, this is exactly a textbook case of what variables are for... storing values.

---

It's possible to have a scenario where this is perfectly acceptable, though.  Consider C#'s properties, which are really just syntactic sugar over classic getter/setter methods.  If we look at those getters in a traditional Java sense, we might have something like this:

```
private thatValue;
public string GetThatValue() { return someString; }

// later...
var myStr = GetThatValue().Substring(1, GetThatValue().Length - 2);
```

In this case it's not an expensive operation, nor would it return different values.  (Threading notwithstanding.)  In this case there's no discernible logical difference between using the variable vs. the method, as the method is simply a wrapper for a class-level variable.

In fact, this approach is often used when the getter has some logic which should always wrap the access to that variable, even for private-only members.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way (using a temporary variable):

```
string temp;
var myStr = (temp = GetThatValue()).Substring(1, temp.Length - 2);
```

or (even shorter):

```
string myStr = (myStr = GetThatValue()).Substring(1, myStr.Length - 2);
```

It works too. You have to change `var` to `string` while declaring the `myStr` variable.

Comment: It should work (and I love the way it does work), but please tell me you don't usually write code like this...

Comment: A clever approach, but I wouldn't recommend it.  "Clever" code isn't always "easily supportable" code.

Comment: @David Yeah, I know, but the question was about a way to simplify the code, not about to make it easily supportable :)

Comment: @romanoza: I don't see why a distinction needs to be drawn between the two.  If something is less intuitive and more difficult to support, then by definition it isn't "simpler".  It may have fewer keystrokes or fewer carriage returns.  But quality of code isn't measured in the number of carriage returns.  (For example, minified JavaScript isn't very easy to support manually.)

Comment: @David OK, but we don't discuss the "quality of code" now. It's a quite separate issue. We don't know the context of this question - is this a part of the production code, or homework, or maybe some kind of syntax experiments.

Comment: @romanoza: The question is asking to "simplify" the code.  So making it "simpler" is exactly what's being asked.  If something is more difficult for a programmer who reads the code later to understand, how is it simpler?  Don't get me wrong, your suggestion "works".  But it's not exactly "simpler".

Answer (score 0):

another altenative - make an extension method:

```
public static class Util
{
    public static string Trim(this string input, int headTrim, int tailTrim)
    {
        return input.Substring(headTrim, input.Length - headTrim - tailTrim);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var str = GetThatValue().Trim(1, 1);
```

---

one-line solution (just for excercise)

regex to remove 1st and last char

```
string result = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(GetThatValue(), "^.", ""), ".$", "");
```